# can i build and package my ios app separately with xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I am using xcodebuild commandline tool to generate my ios app(mainly c++ source code). The command is like

```
xcodebuild -project Application.xcodeproj
```

I want to ask whether can I separate the build phase and package phase, that is to say, first build the binary executable, then at sometime package the app later.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html), `xcodebuild supports various build actions such as build, analyze, and archive that can be performed on your target or scheme. However, build is performed by default when no action is specified`. So, when you want to package, specify action `archive` otherwise just leave it empty as shown in Apple Example in the document.